# How can I know what tiles will be rendered in Google Map?

Tags: ios, google-maps

So initially I want to render a color for each tile on Google Map according to air pollution level.

I have learned how to customize tile layer from [Google's documentation about Tile Layer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/tiles), with which mine looks similar to the following code:

```
class TestTileLayer: GMSSyncTileLayer {   
    override func tileForX(x: UInt, y: UInt, zoom: UInt) -> UIImage! {
        // On every odd tile, render an image.
        if (x % 2 == 0) {
          return UIImage(named: "australia")
        } else {
          return kGMSTileLayerNoTile;
        }
    } 
}
```

Basically, I want to avoid making one request to server for every tile. I would like to know which tiles will be rendered so I may make one request to get air pollution level for all of the tiles at once.

How do I know which tiles will be rendered in Google Maps, given user's current position, zoom level? Is there an API that does this already? I can't seem to find a direct one.

Thank you!